# Chat message with Google Firebase Realtime Database architecture with Unread Message counter and Last Message

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm creating a chat section for android apps. By using Google [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com).
Following task already completed

Create chat node 
2. Separate particular chat thread using two users information. 
3. Read all message for single chat thread.

Now my question is below.
1. How to retrieve last message by single chat thread.
2. How to create a database where i can get counter of unread message counter.

Attachment of my chat database and objective below.

**Current objective.** 
[image]

**Already done.**

[image]

**Firebase database architecture.**

[image]

Now how it will be easier for me to create database for make solution this problem.

Comment: @Mahmudal did you find any solution ? i also have a same problem.

Comment: @Sagar Chavada.. Please check my answer below.

Comment: @Mahmudul @ Sagar Chavada have you implemented messages sent, delivered and read status?

Answer (score 12):

Firebase has it's own example project for building a Chat platform, [Firechat](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/). The project is well explained in it's [doc](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/docs/). The data structure they used can be seen at the end of the doc. You can use their data structure. But for your case, you probably don't have any moderator, so we can make it a little simple than that.

So, you can organize it like this:

```
main-data
|__messageThread  (all data about msgs)
|  |__threadId      (unique id for msg thread)
|     |__chatId     (unique id for chat msgs)
|        |__userId
|        |__userName
|        |__chatMessage
|        |__chatTimestamp
|
|__messageThreadMetadata  
|  |__threadId      
|     |__createdAt     
|     |__createdByUserId
|     |__threadId
|     |__threadName
|     |__threadType (public/private)
|     |__lastChatId (id for last chat, use this to lookup in messageThread)
|
|__users  
|  |__userId      
|     |__userId
|     |__userName
|     |__activeThreads (list of ids of active threads used by user)
|
|__unseenMsgCountData  
|  |__threadId       
|     |__userId
|     |__unseenMsgCount
```

To get back to your question:

1. **How to get last message in a thread?** Please use the node **lastChatId** in a thread and use it to look up the respective **chatMessage**.
2. **How to get unseen message count in a thread for an user?** This is a data that is subjective to each thread and each user. A same thread may have two or more users, each having different unseen message count. So, you can use **unseenMsgCountData** where you can check across a threadId and userId. Whenever anyone posts a chat, increment the unseen msg counter by 1 in that thread for other users, who has the chat thread closed (use the **activeThreads** list from users to track whether he is actively in the thread or not). DO NOT increase the counter for him though, this msg is not his own unseen msg). When any other user opens that thread, reset the value to zero for him.

Hope this helps. Knock here if any further explanation or help is needed.

Comment: how will we update the field 
"messageThreadMetadata / threadId / lastChatId " ?

Clients should do this when a new chat is created, right?

Comment: ```lastChatId``` is a bad idea. The client would have to do an insertion and an update for each chat message sent. The best is to actually listen to the last inserted chat message on the *messageThread* parent.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the last line `unseenMsgCount` in your code snippet needs one more indentation

Comment: @ZZY from my understanding it can be a map with key value pairs where `userId` is the key and `unseenMsgCount` is the value.

Answer (score 3):

this is my workaround.

[image]

as you can see i am making two reference one for message and second recent is for user list.

whenever i tap on user list and open my chat page, In my chat page i m checking condition for receiver id and send status and count to recent refrence in onCreate() of chat page, like this.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        uid = pref.getString("uid", null);
        sender_name = pref.getString("first_name", null);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null && !bundle.isEmpty()){
            recevier_name = bundle.getString("uname");
            receiver_id = bundle.getString("UserId");
        }else {
            recevier_name = "Admin";
            receiver_id = "1";
        }

        chat_date = listAdapter.SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date().getTime());
        if (Integer.parseInt(uid) < Integer.parseInt(receiver_id)) {
            value = String.valueOf(uid + "--*--" + receiver_id);
        } else {
            value = String.valueOf(receiver_id+"--*--"+uid);
        }

myRef1 = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebaseio.com/messages/"+value);

myRef2 = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebaseio.com/recents/"+value);

    myRef2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot != null){
                Map map1 = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if(map1 != null){
                    String rec_id = (String) map1.get("recever_id");
                    if(rec_id.equals(uid)){
                        myRef2.getRef().child("count").setValue("0");
                        myRef2.getRef().child("status").setValue("online");
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    getChat();
}
```

so everytime when i open my chat my status is online if receiver_id is my_id.

now in chat button click i m checking for count if status is not online, like this.

```
private ImageView.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v==enterChatView1)
            {
                message_text = chatEditText1.getText().toString();
                final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("sender_id", uid );
                map.put("recever_id", receiver_id);
                map.put("sender_name", sender_name);
                map.put("recevier_name", recevier_name);
                map.put("text", message_text);
                map.put("text_id", uid);
                map.put("date", chat_date);
                myRef1.push().setValue(map);
              //  myRef2.setValue(map);
               // sendMessage(chatEditText1.getText().toString(), chat_date, UserType.OTHER);

                myRef2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot != null){
                            Map map1 = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            if(map1 != null){
                                String status = (String)map1.get("status");
                                if(map1.containsKey("count")){
                                    if(!status.equals("online")) {
                                        String count = (String) map1.get("count");
                                        int val = Integer.parseInt(count);
                                        map.put("count", String.valueOf(++val));
                                        map.put("status", "offline");
                                        myRef2.setValue(map);
                                        Log.d("VALUE", "YES" + val);
                                    }else {
                                        map.put("count", String.valueOf(0));
                                        map.put("status", "online");
                                        myRef2.setValue(map);
                                        Log.d("VALUE", "No");
                                    }
                                }else {
                                    map.put("count", String.valueOf(1));
                                    map.put("status", "offline");
                                    myRef2.setValue(map);
                                    Log.d("VALUE", "No");
                                }
                            }else {
                                map.put("count", String.valueOf(1));
                                map.put("status", "offline");
                                myRef2.setValue(map);
                                Log.d("VALUE", "first time");
                            }
                        }else {
                            map.put("count", String.valueOf(1));
                            map.put("status", "offline");
                            myRef2.setValue(map);
                            Log.d("VALUE", "first time");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }



            chatEditText1.setText("");

        }
    };
```

and at last when you close your chat page. add status offline to recent in onBackPress() event, like this.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            myRef2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot != null){
                        Map map1 = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        if(map1!= null){
                            String rec_id = (String) map1.get("recever_id");
                            if(rec_id.equals(uid)){
                                myRef2.getRef().child("count").setValue("0");
                                myRef2.getRef().child("status").setValue("offline");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            finish();
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in,
                    R.anim.left_out);  
    }
```

Comment: Good job.. Getting back to you soon.

Comment: Chevada.

Looks I've implemented same way you did.

```One node for recent messages and another for message thread.```

But it looks good you also sending user online and offline.

Everything going well except it is bit slow while first loading.

Comment: yes.. its bit slow for first time, i dont know why.

Comment: @SagarChavada Be careful of having more than 3 levels of nesting. The documentation clearly specifies that more than 3 levels is really a bad idea for your app performance. Try simplifying a bit the structure, making it more flat, that would certainly improve your loading time.

Comment: aHello @SagarChavada How did you get the recent user list from recent child?
I didn't get the logic, can you please explain?
I mean there should be multiple node for other user's too
Like 1--*--137 is for user 1 and 137 and there is another node also named 2--*--122, so how you able to get data from node contains only 1--*-- value?

Comment: @Bhoomit_BB its so simple.. for example when you tap on particular user in chat list.. you get his user_id right.. and you also have your user_id. so as i mention in code... i m getting my id from preference, and getting receiver id on tapping userchat list.. and making value like my_id----**---sender_id. this is how i get perfect value

Comment: @SagarChavada : that i understood perfectly Sagar, but can I use this child for showing the chat list, like whatsapp's home page?
which showing username, last message and count?

Comment: @Bhoomit_BB for that you need different logic..  i'll tell you later sorry. kinda busy here on different project...

Answer (score 1):

@Sagar Chavada

> I have to solve this problem by managing my own variable counting.

For example, there I have a `msg_count` variable that is watching current unread message. Think about when a user sends a message then it `increasing that variable by 1`

For more detail, Please check image below.

[image]

Comment: i solved already  using different logic. now its working same as whatsapp.  thank you though.

Comment: Great job. Can you share an abstract logic of your one :)

Comment: absolutely .. i'll post here.

Comment: @Mahmudal check my answer now.